# Why I am unable to handle two Browsers?

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, selenium

I am trying to run a portion of code in Google Chrome and the rest in Firefox

```
public class flip
{
    static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // starting firefox

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();

        driver1.get("website1");
        driver1.findElement(By.id("id_username")).sendKeys("username");
        driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver1.findElement(By.id("id_password")).sendKeys("password");
        System.out.print("logged in");
        driver1.close();

        driver.get("website-2"); // in firefox
    }
}
```

I am getting following error (when program need to switch browsers).
Both browsers are opening but unable to drive.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
  f.QueryInterface is not a function
  Command duration or timeout: 60.03 seconds
```

Can any one help me where I made mistake ??
(firefox webdriver must be a static..)

Comment: Couple things... I would suggest that you name your driver variables more clearly... something like firefoxDriver and chromeDriver. That way it's perfectly clear which browser you are driving. You didn't specify which line the error is on. `driver1.close;` should be `driver1.close();`

Comment: waht is your selenium and firefox versions. there is clash between them

Comment: @mahsumAkbas  Firefox 40.03 and Selenium 2.47.1

Comment: @JeffC its typo error

Comment: @jeffC it was working till  closing Chrome Browser at driver1.close();

Comment: When you post code, take a minute to make sure that it will compile without errors.

Comment: You should read up on [.implicityWait()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). It doesn't wait when called, it sets a default wait for the entire script.

Comment: @jeffc driver / driver1 . I don't think it will work as it timed out only after 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put http:// on starting of your web address of your firefox driver. it is obligation in that selenium version.

Comment: Thanks Bro its Working